# Any idea when blending modes might be implemented in browsers?

Tags: website-design

I think it would be great for div's/img's to get some of the functionality that "layers" have in photoshop.

Right now, using .png's, div's/img's/etc.'s have their RGB and alpha values.  If you have a 50% transparent layer on top of an 100% opaque layer, the resulting color is a 50/50 blend.  Similarly, if you have a 100% opaque layer on top of another 100% layer, the top layer is the only one that shows.

In photoshop, however, you have blending modes -- multiply, color dodge, screen, overlay, soft light, et al. -- all of which blend the layers using methods different from the method described above.

I made a web site that has a spotlight on the page, but I won't be able to light up the dynamic content that it's pointing at (unless I use JS to do so) because the only blending mode available to me is the "normal" RGB*A method.  There is no option to blend a gobo (picture of the light) using a color dodge, overlay, or soft light method.

Is this a feature that will be coming out soon to any web browsers?

Comment: Interestingly, Internet Explorer has had parts of this since [Version 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) - see e.g. the [Mask filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533013(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks... I'll be sure to test it out to see what it can do.

Answer (score 6):

So far I don't think browsers intend to implement this as a standard browser behaviour, although it'd be great to see it as a CSS attribute for the background!

But you can use a very popular library to achieve the effect you're after.

[The Photoshop Blend modes library from Pixastic](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2009/01/photoshop-blend-modes-with-pixastic.html).

Either you can use it "as is" or probably can modify it to suit your needs better :)

Hope it helps some :)

Comment: This is a great link. It works with `canvas` though, so it will require JavaScript and be rather resource intensive (so it's more for online image processing that for using it as a design element in everyday pages). Still, +1

Comment: I read there that it can be applied to either `img` or `canvas`.. If this is true, it shouldn't take much to modify it to apply ti div backgrounds (but maybe it would) :D Thanks :)