# Adobe Fireworks' blend mode not showing in browser

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Image's blend mode is set as multiply and it is showing the effect correctly in Adobe Fireworks. However, when overlapping the same image with another, separate image in the browser, the effect looks different.

Comment: You have already asked this question and received a very good answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/adobe-fireworks-blend-mode-issue

Comment: arrrrrrrrrr dint get solution thats why i put it again.. :)

Comment: Fireworks' native file format has a .png extension which causes a lot of confusion. While a browser CAN read that native .png format, it's not capable of rendering all the native Fireworks features in it. As such, if you want to use PNGs, you need to EXPORT the .png from Fireworks into a separate file.

Comment: Linked: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/964/any-idea-when-blending-modes-might-be-implemented-in-browsers

Answer (score 2):

The standard JPG/GIF/PNG files Fireworks exports do not support blending modes.

If you blend two images in Fireworks together, it doesn't export two images with blending modes, but rather than one blended image. If you have only one image with a blending mode set, Fireworks exports the image blended with the background (or any other layer(s) behind it). The result is not dynamic and that's why it works as you described.

While the effect is not achievable with just image files, it is achievable to some extent with javascript. See e.g. [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/).

There is some related discussion on Stack Overflow too: [Are photoshop-like blend modes possible in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276859/are-photoshop-like-blend-modes-possible-in-html5)